# Is there the ability to store encrypted data on a desktop app created with tideSDK?

Tags: encryption, tidesdk

I have searched but couldn't find anything. We need to be able to store data offline in our desktop app and we are looking for cross-platform solutions. TideSDK looks promising but I am not sure if it has this functionality.

Comment: Do I understand it right, that you want to save data in an encrypted format, so a user is unable to open the data with any other tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can certainly help there. SQLite certainly provide for encrypted data support and is completely cross-platform and supported by TideSDK. We can use an encrypted database just as easily in TideSDK and could offer support in the API for this. If this is of interest, please get in touch by filing a feature request at https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues.

If we are talking about encryption of the sources - short term there is obfuscation of the JS sources available in 1.3.0 that is due.

Answer (score 0):

We created a Titanium Desktop module to support encrypted SQLite databases last year.  We could help with this and dig out the old code...